# How to configure external IP in guest machine

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization

How to configure an external IP into a guest machine.

The host has eth0 (LAN) and eth1 (external IP). The guest machine should have a LAN ip and the external IP. The host should only have a LAN ip.

Edit 1:

The host should have 192.168.1.5 and the guest machine should have 192.168.1.10 and 201.x.y.z. The configuration of bridge mode for the LAN is easy but how to setup the host eth1 to match my desired setup?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to use virtual network interface in bridge mode.
2. Add LAN ip to both host and quest machines.
3. Configure port forwarding on router to guest machine.

Basically this is same as two machines behind router.

Comment: The host machine have the external ip direct in the eth1 and I have only these external ip. The question is how to setup the external ip in the guest machine and how configure the host as there's no secondary external ip to host.

Comment: Then you SHOULD setup external IP on host machine and do necessary port forwarding to guest machine. In this case guest machine should be connected in NAT mode. How to do it? It depends on chosen virtualisation solution.